# Going from Desktop Excel into Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Generally speaking, Will the following work?

1. download a Google Sheets item into a regular desktop Excel workbook and save it there.
2. edit / work on it and make changes in desktop Excel (no vba)
3. re-upload it to Google sheets and expect all the formulas to be translated correctly and work the same with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
I do it all the time.

Even graphs, for the most part will still work.  Only changing them will be a little different.

The only other thing is that some of your more advanced formatting may go a o little loopy.  Try to keep it simple, and don't go nuts with fonts.

Comment: Wonderful - thank you.  I do a lot of consulting work on MS Office, but because I use VBA a lot in my projects, have virtually no experience in Google sheets.  This project will not have any VBA but I still want to do the "working on it" in desktop Excel for my own convenience, wanting to make sure that generally it will translate back into the client's preferred online format.  Client isn't real picky so I think we will be OK.  Appreciate your answer.

Comment: More over than that - another thing I use it for is translating versions.  I don't even have the newest Office on some machines.  But I can get the sheet into Google, and download it to a previous version.  You can also easily swap Open Office documents at will.  Which I also do, because I use Linux a lot.

Comment: Oh wow - definitely didn't think of that.  Very cool.  I mostly use Office 2007 and 2010.  Can't stand 2013, as they tried to make everything feel and look like a webpage.

Comment: Yeah, that's all fine for the office.  Because that's what they use.  But in all my personal work I use Open Office or Google.  I should point out also that file sharing for Google stuff is spiffy too.  My kids do their homework that way, and rarely have to even print it out.

Comment: I have to look into the whole storage issue for myself in general.  Years ago I backed up my personal & consulting files on adrive.com, which is still around, but seems more suited toward true 'backups' - i.e., you rarely want to download or view it. Recently I'm more focused on Google Drive for its reliability and functionality, but it's pretty easy to fill up 15 free GB. Dropbox seems popular and I do like how it integrates into the mapped drive/folder feel on one's local PC.  Nowadays there are just 'too many' options to know which one to choose-& I'm looking for an option I can do longterm

Comment: Considering I do both of those things already, I don't have new answers about that.

Comment: Roger.  Well Stack o is wagging its finger at me for being chatty.  Thanks again.